# Auto Installing Apps

Tags: android, installation, installation-package

I want to send someone link for the APK once he presses on the download link the apk will be downloaded and opened automatically just like it happens in Google Play!

Possible?

Comment: Im never asked for the code just wanted to know possible or not! because in my knowledge it isn't possible at all but then Im not the Best so maybe there is some work around that may have existed only to know that workaround i asked this questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to send a link to an APK file to somebody. So long as the Web server serves that APK with the correct MIME type (`application/vnd.android.package-archive`), when the user clicks on the link, it should download the file. The user will then usually need to do something else (e.g., tap on a notification) to kick off the installation, though this may vary by browser implementation.

Comment: any example? also the file strictly needs to be on the google play

Comment: @user1898249: I do not understand. If the APK is published on Google Play, send them a link to Google Play.

Comment: this is the thing can't it be like that you have the apk in your server and it gets somehow installed